# Test deletion in ListView with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm quite new with Espresso and I'm trying to test an insertion, deletion and modification in a ListView with custom adapter.

With insertion is simple, I just add a new element and find it inside ListView to check that it has been added.

But the problem comes with deletion, this is what I'm trying to do:

1. Click in first row, on deletion button.
2. Confirm delete.
3. ¿How can I assure that the element has been removed?

I mean, I think that I need to know the content of the item before delete it and then check that the row does not exist any more.

How can I do it? Maybe I'm not in the right path to perform this test and I need to do the test in a different way, but I can not find any information.

```
@Test
public void deleteEdition() {
    startActivityWithintent();

    // push delete button and delete
    onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.listEdition))
            .atPosition(1)
            .onChildView(withId(R.id.imageDelete))
            .perform(click());

    // confirm delete
    onView(withId(R.id.buttonDelete)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.buttonDelete)).perform(click());


    // HOW CAN I CHECK THE ELEMENT DOES NOT EXISTS?
    // onView(withId(R.id.listEdition))
    //        .check(matches(not(withText(????))));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

try to search if there is no view that has a certain text inside its childs, like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.listEdition))
.check(matches(not(hasDescendant(withText("should not exist")))));
```

or if this does not work, search for parts of the string.

```
onView(withId(R.id.listEdition))
.check(matches(not(hasDescendant(withText(containsString("should not exist"))))));
```

it works when i try to reproduce it on my computer.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is that I need to know what is the "text" of the element before delete it. With that text I could check then, that it does not exists.

Comment: What about adding a new row with a test-value stored in a constant, then press the corresponding delete button and later check if there is no more row existing with the value of that constant which you added before?

Comment: It's what I'm doing at the moment. But actually, I'm performing two test in this case: add and delete. Do you know what a I mean?

Comment: i don't really understand, but check the second answer i wrote, maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

store the text of the row you want to delete in a property, like "matchedText"

```
this.matchedText = null;
this.rowCounter = -1;

    onView(new Matcher<View>() {

        @Override
        public boolean matches(Object item) {
            boolean matches = withId(R.id.imageDelete).matches(item);
            if(matches){
                rowCounter++;
                if(rowCounter == 5){ // 5 is an example of the index you want to access     
                    View view = (View) item;
                    matchedText = ((TextView)view.getParent()).getText().toString(); // find the matching view by navigating to the right parent and child to get the text you need 
                    return true
                }
               return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeMismatch(Object item, Description mismatchDescription) {

        }

        @Override
        public void _dont_implement_Matcher___instead_extend_BaseMatcher_() {

        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {

        }
    }).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

after clicking on the delete button you can find out if the row really was deleted with following code:

```
onView(withId(R.id.listEdition))
.check(matches(not(hasDescendant(withText(this.matchedText)))));
```